# Common root of two equation

Tags: common-root

If the root of the equation 3x³+Px³+Qx-37=0 are each one more than the roots of the equation x³-Ax²+Bx-C, where A,B,C,P & Q are constants, then the value of A+B+C  is equal to :

Actually I solved this question by let a root of 3x³+Px³+Qx-37=0 is t and according to question root of x³-Ax²+Bx-C would be t-1
And they both root would be satisfied their respective equation as ;

3t³+Pt³+Qt-37=0
(t-1)³-A(t-1)²+B(t-1)-c=0 => t³-t²(3+A)+t(3+2A)-(A+B+C)-1=0
Now I multiplied 3 both side of eqn
And got
3t³-3t²(3+A)+3t(3+2A)-3(A+B+C)-3=0

Then I put
37= 3(A+B+C)+3
34\3=A+B+C
= 11.33
But I don't know that it my right approach to this question

Please tell me can we do this question like this ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did you mean cubic equations? An equation of degree 3 is a cubic, not a quadratic.

Comment: @Soni, Your method is certainly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach:

Let $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ be the 3 roots of $x^3-Ax^2+Bx-C=0$,

then we have
$$x^3-Ax^2+Bx-C=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

and

$$x^3+\frac{P}{3}x^2+\frac{Q}{3}x-\frac{37}{3}=(x-\alpha-1)(x-\beta-1)(x-\gamma-1)\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

In equation $(1)$, if we put $x=-1$, we have

$$-1-A-B-C=(-1-\alpha)(-1-\beta)(-1-\gamma)$$

$$A+B+C=-1-(-1-\alpha)(-1-\beta)(-1-\gamma)$$

Job is done if we can find the value of

$$(-1-\alpha)(-1-\beta)(-1-\gamma)$$

from equation (2)